# railsのフリマアプリに環境変数を設定したいです

Tags: ruby-on-rails

現在rubyでフリマアプリを作成しております。クレジットカードでの購入機能を実装したいのですが、実行できなかったため相談させていただきました。以下が手順と不具合です。

手順は `vim ~/.zshrc` でインサートモードに移行し、下記のクレジットカードの秘密鍵・公開鍵を追記する。

```
export PAYJP_SECRET_KEY='sk_test_*************'
export PAYJP_PUBLIC_KEY='pk_test_*************'
```

`:wq` と入力して保存して終了

となる予定でしたが、syntaxエラーが発生してしまい現在に至ります。

コードとしては

```
export PAYJP_SECRET_KEY='sk_test_123456789'
export PAYJP_PUBLIC_KEY='pk_test_987654321'
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"~/zshcr" 2L, 118B
```

この一番上の２行(実際には異なる変数を入れております)を入力したところ、下記のエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    20: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    19: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.17.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    18: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.17.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    17: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    16: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    15: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    14: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
    13: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    12: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
    11: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands/credentials/credentials_command.rb:32:in `edit'
    10: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/command/helpers/editor.rb:26:in `catch_editing_exceptions'
     9: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands/credentials/credentials_command.rb:33:in `block in edit'
     8: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands/credentials/credentials_command.rb:67:in `change_credentials_in_system_editor'
     7: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:55:in `change'
     6: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:69:in `writing'
     5: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:27:in `write'
     4: from /Users/sunow/projects/furima-39442/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:42:in `deserialize'
     3: from /Users/sunow/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:277:in `load'
     2: from /Users/sunow/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:390:in `parse'
     1: from /Users/sunow/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse_stream'
/Users/sunow/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 6 column 151 (Psych::SyntaxError)
sunow@oobaketsukinonoMacBook-Air furima-39442 % EDITOR="vim" bin/rails credentials:edit

File encrypted and saved.
sunow@oobaketsukinonoMacBook-Air furima-39442 % EDITOR="vim" bin/rails credentials:edit

File encrypted and saved.
sunow@oobaketsukinonoMacBook-Air furima-39442 % EDITOR="vim" bin/rails credentials:edit

File encrypted and saved.
sunow@oobaketsukinonoMacBook-Air furima-39442 % EDITOR="vim" bin/rails credentials:edit

File encrypted and saved.
sunow@oobaketsukinonoMacBook-Air furima-39442 % vim ~/zshcr
sunow@oobaketsukinonoMacBook-Air furima-39442 %
```

このエラーを解消し、環境変数を設定したいです。'dotenv'等のgemは使用しておりません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim で開くファイル名を間違えている気がします。`~/.zshrc` を開くはずが、あなたは `~/zshcr` に環境変数を記載しているように見えます。

Comment: ご指摘の通り違うファイルを開いていたようで、解決しました。ありがとうございます！